# How to calculate SHA in parallel?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, hash, sha

Calculation of SHA variants is simple, you create a message digest, update it with data and get the result.
  But, if we have many cores, how to do that in parallel? You can not calculate it on blocks and hash the results, because the overall result will not be correct.
  How to do this calculation in parallel, getting the same result?

The following is sequential java example:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class BenchmarkSha256 {

  public static void main(String... args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    int size = 1024 * 1024;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
      md.update(bytes, 0, size);
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(String.format("%1$064x", new java.math.BigInteger(1, md.digest())));
    System.out.println(String.format("%d ms", (endTime - startTime) / 1000000));
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a sufficiently long string to digest to make it worth digesting it using multiple threads? Because if you have multiple strings to hash, then just distribute your strings over threads, and you'll have your solution. What does your program do besides hashing?

Comment: SHA variants are all chained hash functions.  They work on blocks and besides the initial hash every subsequent hashes depends on hashes from the previous block.  So you cannot parallelize a "normal" SHA hash.  You could of course define you own "n-SHA{1,256,etc.}" which would split the input in *n* parts, compute the SHA hash of each part in parallel, and then XOR the *n* hashes into your final hash.  But that wouldn't be a "normal" SHA.

Comment: @JB Nizet : I want to hash large files fast, so I need fine-grained parallelism. For example, as in the code, we need the hash of 1GB of zeroes, fast.

Comment: @user988052 : do you mean that there is *no way* to get this result faster on multi-core machine?

Comment: @Hristo Hristov: indeed.  As far as I know there's no way to parallelize chained hash functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use multiple threads you need to be able to perform tasks in parallel.

AFAIK, you can only calculate a message digest processing each block in turn.  As such you can only use one thread to calculate each digest value.  However, if you can produce multiple values or merge them, you can do it is parallel.

Comment: The question is, how to do it with multiple threads, working on multiple blocks? Is merging possible with SHA?

Comment: You will get multiple SHA digests, one for each block/thread.  You can't use multiple threads to create one standard SHA digest.

Comment: So, the answer to the quiestion is: "This is not possible!" ?

Comment: Not without changing the result.